# Switch view - Django

Tags: python, django

when I try to render a page does not work, here's a quick example, what I do is to send data from a form from the html with a button, 
and then redirect it to another page.

The data arrive correctly and I've checked from the server.

views.py

```
def index(request):
    context={}
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...    
        form=list(dict(request.POST)['data[]'])
        return render(request,'bala/pdf.html',{'form':form})
    else:
        return render(request,'bala/index.html',context)
```

Comment: I tried to "redirect" but I can not make it work, I get this when I click on the button: "[07 / Feb / 2016 1:22:45]" POST / bala / HTTP / 1.1 "302 0
[07 / Feb / 2016 1:22:45] "GET / bala / pdf / HTTP / 1.1" 200 2919
"

Comment: Could you post your HTML files and your urlconf?